# Что за вид адресных ссылок

Tags: php, html, ссылки, адрес

Я знаю ссылки скажем example.com/index.html или axample.th/ololo.php?q=089564.

Но что такое, например, 'https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Город_потерянных_детей' ?
Как здесь переданы данные? Это такой вид get? Или там действительно есть файл "Город_потерянных_детей"? Мне кажется это как-то переменная передаётся, только не пойму куда и как (то есть там есть файл https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/index.php который обрабатывает переменную и формирует ответ пользователю?).

Comment: Непонятно в чём вопрос, `Город_потерянных_детей` — это логически абсолютно то же самое, что и `index.html` и `ololo.php` из первых примеров. Файл с таким названием может существовать или не существовать — всё зависит только от того, как автор сайта захотел реализовать свой сайт

Comment: А к чему вопрос. Такие ссылки называются "Человекопонятный URL" или как-то по другому. Но по термину "Человекопонятный URL" есть статья в википедии, которая даст основные понятия о том как это работает. А так же может дать дальнейшее направление поисков если есть задача реализации таких же ссылок на своем сайте.

Comment: Конкретно в случае MediaWiki абсолютно все запросы перенаправляются в один-единственный файл [index.php](https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki/blob/1.39.0/index.php), при этом веб-сервер настраивается так, чтобы название файла преобразовывалось в GET-параметр `title` (например, через [.htaccess](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Short_URL/wiki/Page_Title_--_.htaccess) для веб-сервера Apache), а дальше [в php-коде просто считывается](https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki/blob/1.39.0/includes/MediaWiki.php#L83) этот самый GET-параметр `title`

Comment: Я уже час читаю мануалы по этому человекопонятному url (ЧПУ), это то, что нужно. Напишите в ответ человекопонятный юрл я поставлю галку на ответ. Спасибо за помощь, похоже информации в достатке, дальше разберусь. Просто мне на сайт нужно добавить короткие ru или ua для языка, по этому изучаю, как это сделать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это ЧПУ - человекопонятный URL. Когда идёт запрос в сервер, то строку запроса можно изменять через файл htaccess, или доставать отдуда данные и переделывать всё в довольно громоздкий GET запрос. Это делается через mod_rewrite. Поэтому и используют ЧПУ, чтобы адресная строка была понятна пользователю.

Я только начинаю это изучать, вот на этом ресурсе очень толково объясняеться, как это работает https://hackware.ru/?p=5564

P. S. Не наступайте на мои грабли - используйте для настройки и тестирования htaccess хрум, потому что огненный лис кешировал правила, что изрядно съело мои нервы, пока я не догадался, в чем же причина.

Comment: Лис ничего не знает ни про какие правила, они отрабатывают на стороне сервера. Вероятно, вы просто забыли выключить кэширование страниц путём прописывания правильного HTTP-заголовка Cache-Control или типа того

Comment: Он, если я правильно понял, запоминает редиректы с кодом R=301, потому что я чисто для теста стёр файл htaccess и применялись старые правила. Но стоило сбросить кеш браузера, и всё нормально. А вот хром моментально реагирует на изменения в файле htaccess, я лично проверял. К тому же, не только у меня была проблема с этим. Вот ещё примеры https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/18865/rule-caching-in-htaccess-how-to-force-apache-to-re-read-a-modified-htacces   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7743980/apache-how-to-disable-browser-caching-while-debugging-htaccess  (там 2 ссылки)

Comment: Редиректы 301 существуют специально для того, чтобы сделать редирект **навсегда**. Если вы пытались делать R=301 не навсегда — значит вы использовали его не по назначению, то есть неправильно